# Two verbs in future tense

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

This is a sentence in present tense, how could change the tense, when another verb is needed to use?

> I want to see it.(Present)
>
> I will want it to see.(Future)(because I know I can't stop seeing her and maybe this is my weak side.)

Answer (score 1):

The future of

> I want to see it

is simply

> I will want to see it

This expresses a future wish to see it.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?